# BigQuery: Recreate GA segments based on landing page - inconsistent metrics

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create a table on BigQuery with our main **Google Analytics segments** and their **metrics** (sessions, users, bounce rate, transactions, revenue, time on site), broken down by **dimensions** (device, news/returning).

The following query works just fine and results are spot on with Google Analytics:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(date,1,6) AS date,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium, r'^(cpc|ppc|cpa|cpm|cpv|cpp|display)') THEN 'paid'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'organic' THEN 'organic'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE '(none)' THEN 'direct'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'referral' THEN 'referral'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'social' THEN 'social'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS segment,
  COALESCE(totals.newVisits, 0) = 1 AS first_visit,
  device.deviceCategory AS device,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
  COUNT(totals.bounces) AS bounces,
  SUM(totals.timeOnSite) AS session_duration,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
  SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
FROM
  `xxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180930`
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4
```

As you can see, the query works just fine for all segments based on **trafficSource.medium** only. My problem is that I need to create segments based on **landing page** as well.

I joined the original table with a subquery for getting the unnested landing pages (please check query bellow -> additional dimensions and metrics removed for simplicity).

That strategy is not working: now all my metrics like **sessions** stoped matching the ones in Google Analytics.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium,  
r'^(cpc|ppc|cpa|cpm|cpv|cpp|display)') THEN 'paid'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'organic' AND landing_blog LIKE 'not blog' THEN 'organic not blog'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'organic' AND landing_blog LIKE 'blog' THEN 'organic landing blog'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE '(none)' THEN 'direct'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'referral' THEN 'referral'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'social' THEN 'social'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS segment,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
  `xxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180930` AS ga
JOIN (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath,  r'^/blog/') THEN 'blog'
      ELSE 'not blog'
    END AS landing_blog
    -- Uses the knowledge that hits are stored in chronological order
  FROM
    `xxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180930`,
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.hitNumber = 1
    AND hits.type LIKE 'PAGE') AS landing
ON
  ga.visitId = landing.visitId
GROUP BY 1
```

I would appreciate any help in either correcting the second query or suggesting a different strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from work helped me find the error. Here's the final query:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(date,1,6) AS date,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(trafficSource.medium, r'^(cpc|ppc|cpa|cpm|cpv|cpp|display)') THEN 'paid'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'organic'
  AND landing_blog LIKE 'not blog' THEN 'organic not blog'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'organic' AND landing_blog LIKE 'blog' THEN 'organic landing blog'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE '(none)' THEN 'direct'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'referral' THEN 'referral'
    WHEN trafficSource.medium LIKE 'social' THEN 'social'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS segment,
  COALESCE(totals.newVisits, 0) = 1 AS first_visit,
  device.deviceCategory AS device,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ga.fullVisitorId) AS users,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
  COUNT(totals.bounces) AS bounces,
  SUM(totals.timeOnSite) AS session_duration,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
  SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
FROM
  `xxxx.ga_sessions_2018*` AS ga
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    fullVisitorId,
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r'^/blog/|^/lab/') THEN 'blog'
      ELSE 'not blog'
    END AS landing_blog
  FROM
    `xxxxx.ga_sessions_2018*`,
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.isEntrance = TRUE) AS landing
ON
  ga.visitId = landing.visitId
  AND ga.fullVisitorId = landing.fullVisitorId
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're doing and I can tell you may run into problems when repurposing that solution.

Right now what you're doing is filtering the hits based on the segment conditions. Because the session data is persisted across hits you won't have any problems and it will behave like a session based segment does in the GA interface.

But, if you are to do the same with, say, events, or try to do a GA segment based on users (like source/medium from the first visit) then your solution will fall short. It will also fall short when you have internal linking in the website with utm parameters (you'll see only the first part of the session, which will impact your metrics and ratios).

I suggest you to do the following:

1. Create a View that defines the segment and returns only all the session IDs or user IDs (if you are to use GA's segments based on users) that belong to the segment
2. Create your metrics/performance query and add to the `where` clause that session ids or user ids need to be present in the view. Or you can implement this with a JOIN and a case statement.

This way you have a very reusable and modular query, where the filter is defined in one place and the metrics in another. If you want to add more segments it is easy. If you want to change one segment it is also easy